# Prevent bootstrap modal from closing when inputs are not filled

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a grid of students and a button. When a user clicks it, a new modal is shown.
In the modal there are some inputs and a button "save".
When a user clicks save via angular, the new student is added and the modal is closed.
I want to prevent the modal from closing when the input are not filled.
How can I do this?
In other words, I want the save button to not do the job of ng-click and data-dismiss="modal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable button if inputs didn't validated (required, max, etc.) like this:

```
<form role="form" name="formInTheModal" id="formInTheModal" class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="inpDummy" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Enter</label>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inpDummy"
                    ng-model="inpDummy" maxlength="50" required>
         </div>
     </div>
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doJob()"
        ng-disabled="formInTheModal.$invalid" > DO
    </button>
</form>
```